# Problem in cursor movement when the text is entered in textbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Textbox textwrap property is set to wrap.

My scenario is enter the text in textbox from SIP. When cursor reaches almost at the end of line may be 3 or 4 char left for line change just enter space so that it should came to next line. But after pressing space 4 or 5 time or more the cursor will not come to next line moreover it will not shown . It will come to next line when i enter some char.

I think it should came to next line because user may want to enter some space. is this can be fixed.

Comment: Is there a question here or are you just complaining about the behaviour of the control?

Comment: i m just finding out that is this behavior can be changed. If yes then how? If no then it must be bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other property you need to set on the TextBox is AcceptsReturn to true.